# jquery index() - hover list item, show content with same index

Tags: jquery

I'm having a jquery issue with a small menu I have.  I have a list of menu items.  When I hover over one of the list items, I would like to show the content from a list of divs that shares the same index as the list item.  This needs to be dynamic do allow any number of menu items and content items.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#leftnav li").each(function(){
        $(this).mouseover(function() {
            //SHOW div that shares same index as this li
        });
        $(this).mouseout(function() {
            //HIDE div that shares same index as this li
        });
    });
});

<ul id="leftnav">
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
</ul>

<div id="content">
    <div>Content 1</div>
    <div>Content 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd probably use the [hover()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover#overout) method to simplify this (or the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin, which solves a few other problems like issues with rapid mouse movement).

```
$(function() {
     $('#leftnav li').hover(
          function() {
               var idx = $('#leftnav li').index(this);
               $('#content div').eq(idx).show();
          },
          function() {
               var idx = $('#leftnav li').index(this);
               $('#content div').eq(idx).hide();
          }
      }):
});
```

Comment: Nice solution. Much prettier than my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
    $(function() {
        $('#leftnav li').mouseover(function() {
            var index = $('#leftnav li').index($(this));
            $('#content').find('div:eq(' + index + ')').show();
        }).mouseout(function() {
            var index = $('#leftnav li').index($(this));
            $('#content').find('div:eq(' + index + ')').hide();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

use `prevAll().length`. Much better than .index